# How to persist checkbox checked state after page reload?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I am unable to persist **checkbox** checked after page is refreshed.

Comment: set the value in local storage and get when the page is refreshed

Comment: if want complete solution show me the sample of your code

Answer (score 3):

You need to use cookies for this... As soon as user clicks on check box, store its state into a cookie and just fetch the cookie value on page load to prepoulate the checkboxes as they were in previous selection.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
</div>
<button>Check all</button>
```

**Fetching checkboxes value and making a cookie out of them**

```
var checkboxValues = {};
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
  checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
});
$.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
```

**Function to read cookies to prepopulate on load**

```
function repopulateCheckboxes(){
  var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
  if(checkboxValues){
    Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
      var checked = checkboxValues[element];
      $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
    });
  }
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/ya14c4gt/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this on server side. Either with PHP, ASP.NET or whatever you use.

This is the only way.

**Or**, if your website is client-side only, then you would have to implement it without any page refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I do it:

```
    <html>

<input type="checkbox" <?php echo file_get_contents(".cktest"); ?> onclick="getFileFromServer('write_ckfile.php?target=.cktest&value='+this.checked, function(text){ show_write(text)});"> cktest with php<br/>


<!-- with ajax read the checked attribut from file -->
<input id="withajax" type="checkbox" onclick="getFileFromServer('write_ckfile.php?target=.cktest&value='+this.checked, function(text){ show_write(text)});"> cktest with ajax<br/>


<script>
function getFileFromServer(url, doneCallback) {
    var xhr;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    function handleStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            doneCallback(xhr.status == 200 ? xhr.responseText : null);
        }
    }
}

function show_write(text) {
  //alert(text);
}


// 
getFileFromServer(".cktest", function(x) { document.getElementById("withajax").checked=x;} );

</script>

</html>
```

and the file write_ckfile.php:

```
    <?php
$strtarget=$_GET['target'];


$status=$_GET['value']=="true"?"checked":"";
file_put_contents($strtarget, $status );



?>
```

I hope this helps.
MiKL~