# How can I retain my checkbox status even if I refresh the page?

Tags: html, ajax, checkbox, html-table

I created a table with checkboxes. When I click on a checkbox, I can see the sign "✓". But when I refresh the page, the checkbox goes automatically to default version.
If I click on a empty checkbox or clik on a already "checked" checkbox and refresh the page, I wanna see my changes as they are since I will need to take the value of the checkboxes int the feature.

```
<!-- Department's Table -->
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Authorisation</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>0555 555 55 55</td>
                    <td>test@test.com.tr</td>
                    <td><div style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="checkbox"><div></div></input>
                      </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  </tr>                  
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <!-- End Authorisation For Departments Table Example -->
```

I tried to use Ajax but couldn't do anything. My aim is to create a table with questions and send the link of it to someone in order to give a score between 1-9. But everyone is giving a score to a different person for different question. Therefore there will be admin panel to give authorisation for both the questions and persons to someone who will rate. Therefore, I am trying to create another table called "Authorisation for departments". In this table ther will be checkboxes and with those checkboxes we will give permission to someone in order to rate someone. Of course, no one see who rate him/her.
Therefore, I created a test table for permission but when I refresh the page, my checkbox goes to default status. If I checked a checkbox, I want it to stay like that when I refresh the page and when I unchecked it, again it should remain as it is when I refresh the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to persist checkbox checked state after page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671918/how-to-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload)

Comment: For me it sounds like you describe 2 tasks: 1) Persist values on client side. 2) Show selected values after retrieving values from back-end database. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a checkbox remain checked even after refreshing the page, you need to save the state of the checkbox in some form of storage, such as local storage or cookies. Local storage is a convenient way to store small amounts of data in the user's browser.
First give your checkbox an id. Then do the following in your Js file or script tag.
Try this if you have multiple inputs.

```
// Function to save checkbox states to Local Storage
function saveCheckboxStates() {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked);
  });
}

// Function to load checkbox states from Local Storage
function loadCheckboxStates() {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    const savedState = localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id);
    if (savedState !== null) {
      checkbox.checked = savedState === 'true';
    }
  });
}

// Attach event listener to the checkboxes to save their states
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', saveCheckboxStates);
});

// Load checkbox states on page load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadCheckboxStates);
```

Comment: It worked for the first cell that contains checkbox but when I try it for the checkboc that is next to the first checkbox, it didn't work. How can I do this for spesific cells in a row?

Comment: This will only work for the targeted checkbox with the specific id which we are using. If you want to do it for many checkboxes then give same checkbox id to all.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. (Like  id="checkbox1" and id="checkbox2") And of course, I changed ( document.getElementById('checkbox2') ) part. Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: I have updated the code according to your requirement. This will work

Comment: I tried it by changing the ids but again it worked for the first checkbox and didn't work for the others.

Comment: In this updated code , we are not targeting input by id, we are targeting all  inputs of type checkbox.

Comment: Sorry for that. Then, I guess I put it to the wrong tag to try it. I put it bewtween <td></td>, is it wrong?

Comment: doesnot matter. Depends on your requirement

Answer (score -1):

try using the browsers storage (local storage or cookies). so next time you render the page check of the state is there and check the ones that are checked and if the state is not there it means the user was not there before so render the default page.